# Square Floating Action Button

Tags: java, android, android-support-library

I created a FloatingActionButton in my Android app using Support Library but I noticed that this button is square, not cirсle.
Drawable is okay...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: @Blackbelt icon of "+". It is ok.

Comment: Add **xmlns:app=h ttp://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto** to the root layout. and then add **app:borderWidth="0dp"**

Comment: use app:borderWidth="0dp" for api level below 21 and app:borderWidth="16dp" to api level 21 and above